# Reverse pkg-config?

Tags: pkg-config

Suppose using the `pkg-config` I can find which link flags are needed add a library to my code, suppose if I need cairo libraries to add, I can find the appropriate `-l` flag by

```
> pkg-config --libs cairo
> -lcairo
```

How do I find the reverse (i.e. link flags --> library name)? 
Suppose I want to know which library will be added by invoking `-lm` flag, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I want to know which library will be added by invoking -lm flag, how do I do that?

The part after the `-l` is the name of the library.  Its binary is prefixed with `lib`, so you can find them by that name;

```
> whereis libm
libm: /usr/lib64/libm.a /usr/lib64/libm.so

> whereis libcairo
libcairo: /usr/lib64/libcairo.so
```

Etc.

If `whereis` does not say anything, you can also try grepping the output of `ldconfig -p` (see `man ldconfig`):

```
> ldconfig -p | grep "libm.so"
    libm.so.6 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib64/libm.so.6
    libm.so.6 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib/libm.so.6
    libm.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib64/libm.so
```

Notice in this case I've appended "libm" with ".so", which is not necessary, but it saves matching against "libmfoo...", "libmbar...", etc.  Since `-l` refers to linking shared object (`.so`) libraries, this should be pretty foolproof.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, in my machine the `whereis` command does not give anything. Anyway I am managing it with the `locate` command for the time being.

Comment: Yes, `whereis` is not really intended for finding (shared) libraries, although it generally does work and the usage and output are simple.  For cases where it doesn't I've added a paragraph above about grepping `ldconfig -p` instead.

Comment: If you don't know whether the library is installed, `apt-file search` is better.